# Grub failing to install showing sata link hard reseting

Tags: grub2, partitioning, hard-drive, grub-efi, sata

While using ubuntu16.04 my laptop  got hanged.After restarting it was kept on hanging and in text mode It was showing error

> sata1 exception emask 0x10 sact 0x0 serr 0x40400000 action 0xe frozen
>   irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed.
>   Satalink hard reseting

So I tried installing 18.04lts
But grub  was failing to install. I tried installing using MBR and GPT both with no success. Thinking that it may be  hard disk fail I Checked disk for error from live boot pendrive and it shown no errors or bad sectors in HDD

[smartctl output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzYm5.jpg)

I tried changing live pendrive with 2difrrent iso images but still grub installation was failing

Some one suggested to clean hard disk terminal so I did cleaned it and now it in live boot mode

The output of

```
dmesg
```

[Dmesg output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXR7e.jpg)

And as you can see in above image it is showing diffrent error

It is clearly not bad HDD or bad  iso image issue

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Are drives set to AHCI mode in UEFI, not RAID, Intel SRT nor IDE? Unless RAID 0.

Comment: Lenovo  ideapad Z510 , CPU:-Intel I7 4th gen, GPU:-Nvidea720M, Drives are in AHCI mode

Comment: Are you using nomodeset boot parameter? You need that until you add nVidia proprietary driver from Ubuntu repository. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Older version of Ubuntu but same laptop: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2232124 The nVidia driver: https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: I turned off Nvidea  device  from bios

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/